# NiFi HA-Proxy configuration instructions

Tags: apache-nifi

I have 3 node NiFi cluster and want to setup NiFi HA-Proxy.

Can someone please help me with instructions to setup HA-Proxy?

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 2):

Pierre Villard has [written instructions](https://pierrevillard.com/2017/02/10/haproxy-load-balancing-in-front-of-apache-nifi/) on doing this.

I generally try to avoid "link only" answers, but the contents are too much to post here.